# Is it possible to open web application project from web in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, project, web

I been using Web Application project with Visual Studio 2003 for many years, and I finally decided to migrate to Visual Studio 2010 Pro. I did use the convert wizard with success to migrate my Web Application project.

However, there is one thing that I am not able to do with VS 2010 that I was able to do with VS 2003 : open a project from web. (important : here I mean a Web Application Project, not a Web Site Project)

VS 2010 only seems to offer the option to open Web Site Project from a web location. I want to keep using Web Application Project, and I am only able to open Web Application Project on my own computer or on my network, but I am not able anymore to open a Web Application Project using http location. This feature was available in VS 2003 and I really can't find the same in VS 2010.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

new project -> language -> web -> ASP.NET Web Application

Comment: I did that already, it only provide the option to create a Web Application locally. I need to be able to both create and open a Web Application using http (like in VS 2003).